# Fread get different content for a .txt and a .jpeg file

Tags: c, jpeg, fread

I'm getting only 4 bytes in my buffer when I try to read the whole file (weight a lot more than 4B). But when I'm reading a .txt file, I successfully recover the whole file content.

I've searched in the fopen man, in the malloc mand and in the fread man, but I cant' understand why.

```
char* readFile(char* path)
{
    /*VARIABLES*/
    FILE *inFile;
    long inFileSize;
    long readSize;
    char *buffer = NULL;

    /*OPEN FILES*/
    inFile = fopen(path,"rb");

    /*ERROR HANDLING : FILES*/
    if(!inFile) {
        return "";
    }

    /*GETTING FILE SIZE*/
    fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    inFileSize = ftell(inFile);
    rewind(inFile);

    printf("The file is %ld bytes long\n",inFileSize);

    /*ALLOCATING MEMORY*/
    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (inFileSize + 1) );

    /*READ THE CONTENT AND PUT IT IN THE BUFFER*/
    readSize = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), inFileSize, inFile);

    /*ERROR HANDLING : readed size != to the file size*/
    if (inFileSize != readSize)
    {
        printf("Freeing buffer\n");
        free(buffer);
        buffer = NULL;
    }

    /*ADDING THE END STRING CODE*/
    buffer[inFileSize] = '\0';

    /*CLOSE THE FILE*/
    fclose(inFile);
    return buffer;
}
```

Also, when I change the image extension from .jpeg to .txt, I still get 4 bytes only.

Can you help me ?

Comment: You can start with trapping any fseek error

Comment: @Grantly I don't have any fseek ones :( . In fact, the variable "inFileSize" which gets it value with fseek, is correct.

Comment: FYI: [don't cast malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: *How* do you know how many bytes you're getting?  You wouldn't be treating the jpeg file as a string, would you?  And FWIW, `fseek(inFile, 0, SEEK_END);` is explicitly undefined behavior per the C standard.  It may work on your implementation, but it's non-portable.

Comment: @Barmar Yup, let met take it out ! Thanks, by the way.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I know it because I strlen the result of the function.

Comment: @Amperclock JPEG is a binary file, not a text string. `strlen()` returns the position of the first 0 byte, JPEG has zero bytes inside the file.

Comment: If you want to know how much as read, print `readSize`.

Comment: Yep, strlen is the worst thing to use on a binary character array

Comment: Also, you have undefined behavior when you do `buffer[inFileSize]` after `buffer = NULL;`.

Comment: @Barmar I Think I get it. So what should I use instead ? sizeof don't work (and that's normal).

Comment: Just use `readSize`.

Comment: @Barmar So to access this value outside my function, I need to call the pointer of it.

Comment: You need to return the size from the function somehow. You could return a structure that contains the size and pointer to the array.

Comment: @Barmar I'll return a 2D array (char** myarray). The first slot is the content, the second is the readSize.

Comment: Yous can use `stat` to find the size of the file.

Comment: @Amperclock That's a silly way to do it. Arrays should be used for uniform data, structures should be used for heterogeneous data.

Comment: Discussion of the issues around using `fseek` and `ftell` to get the file length can be found [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/FIO19-C.+Do+not+use+fseek%28%29+and+ftell%28%29+to+compute+the+size+of+a+regular+file)

Comment: regarding: `buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (inFileSize + 1) );`  1) the returned value from `malloc()` has type `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc  2) the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect and just clutters the code.  3) Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.